# Iterating through a list of numbers and adding them to <tr> tags

Tags: python, html

So I have this table, and I want to go through in Python, and find all of the `<tr>` tags, and turn them into `<tr id="NUMBER HERE">` where the number will be a number from a list which is in this format:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '47']
```

What is the best way to do this?

So basically, the first `<tr>` would become `<tr id="1">` the second would become `<tr id="2">`, etc.

It is NOT always sequential, as you can see from it going from 20 to 47.

The table is stored as a string.

I should specify, currently, it is a string with multiple  tags, i.e. `<html><table><tr>blah</tr><tr>blahblah</tr></table></html>` - VERY oversimplified. I want it to search for the instances of `<tr>` in the string and replace each with `<tr id="NUMBER">`, based on the position of the tr versus the next number in the list.

Comment: Your question doesn't read well - if you want a decent answer consider a re-write

Comment: I have failed to parse your question

Comment: Sorry, didn't put code tags around my HTML.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/):

```
import lxml.html as LH

html_table='''
<table>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
</table>
'''

nums=['1','2','20','47','50']
doc=LH.fromstring(html_table)
for tr,n in zip(doc.xpath('//tr'),nums):
    tr.attrib['id']=n
print(LH.tostring(doc,pretty_print=True))
```

yields

```
<table>
<tr id="1"></tr>
<tr id="2"></tr>
<tr id="20"></tr>
<tr id="47"></tr>
<tr id="50"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How would this be outputted as a variable?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

lxml option is good. If one is open for external package ([sphc](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/sphc) here) below is an interesting option.

```
import sphc

nums = ['1','2','20','47','50']

tf = sphc.TagFactory()

table = tf.TABLE()
table.rows = [tf.TR(id=num) for num in nums]

print (table)
```